# Parse xml in titanium

Tags: java, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have response data from a server. I need to extract the resultant content value from the XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Result>Token1234567890</Result>
        </Response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried with `getElementsByTagName('Response').text;`

How can I get Element content for the Result which is `Token1234567890`?

Comment: If you have a valid answer, you should accept an answer so that it does not show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
getElementsByTagName('Response').text;
```

With

```
getElementsByTagName('Response').innerXML;
```

It's an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tokenData = responseData.getElementsByTagName('Response').item(0).text;
```

If i am using above code its working fine!